Using Quarto, how to render a self-contained HTML file that contains shinylive-r code?
Description of issue
I am trying to create a self-contained HTML file with Quarto, that contains a {shinylive-r} code block, but I am having issues with this.
Is it possible to do this? Please see below to re-create what I am doing.
Note: I am able to properly render my HTML file if I exclude the self-contained: true option in my yaml header. However, my goal is to create a single self-contained HTML file.
Steps to recreate
I have the below .qmd file called matts_reports.qmd:
    ---
    title: "My document"
    format: html
    filters: 
    - shinylive
    self-contained: true
    ---
    
    # Hello, world!
    
    ## shinylive Code Block
    
    Here is a shinylive codeblock:
    
    ```{shinylive-r}
    #| standalone: true
    #| viewerHeight: 800
    #| 
    library(shiny)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput(
            inputId = "bins",
            label = "Number of bins:",
            min = 1,
            max = 50,
            value = 30
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
        )
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x <- faithful$waiting
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        hist(x,
          breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
          xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
          main = "Histogram of waiting times"
        )
      })
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

However, when I run this (i.e click render in R Studio) I get a couple of issues:

The shinylive code block renders as text in the browser, rather than actually runnning a shiny app.



I see this issue in my R Background Jobs output:

Watching files for changes
/shinylive.js (404: Not Found)


Yeah I've tried this too and the shinylive-r part of the html won't display the app. Saw this issue in the quarto gitlab as to why this occurs.
A possible workaround was shown here, but I didn't try it. Only useful if I want to view it myself as a stand alone html but not if I want to share the html with others.
